# Нужна ли FragmentActivity

Tags: android, android-fragment, activity, android-appcompat

Читаю сейчас книгу "Программирование для профессионалов 2 издание 2016". В книге знают и рассказывают о `Support Library`, но почему то используют `FragmentActivity` вместо `AppCompatActivity`, разве есть разница, разве `AppCompatActivity` не лучше ?

Comment: класс `AppCompatActivity` это наследник класса `FragmentActivity`, который расширяет возможности Activity для использования `Toolbar`, `ActionBar`, смотрите исходники и читайте офф документацию, а вопроса лучше/хуже тут вообще не стоит

Comment: @georgehardcore, почему же не стоит, если `AppCompatActivity` наследует `FragmentActivity`, значит понадобилась большая функциональность, и `FragmentActivity` устарел. Может ли быть сейчас необходимость отказываться от `AppCompatActivity` и использовать `FragmentActivity` ?

Comment: @pavlofff Спасибо, вынесите это в ответ и я помечу его как правильный

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Сами по себе классы фреймворков не имеют признаков лучше/хуже (кроме объявленных устаревшими, а это отметка *deprecated* в документации, а не чье то частное мнение). У каждого есть свое назначение и причины использовать. Разных классов, выполняющих одинаковые функции или актуальных классов, которые выполняют аналогичную работу лучше других, в API (фреймоврках) как правило не имеется.

`AppCompatActivity` используется для имплементации темы *AppCompat*, более того, если вы используете тему *AppCompat*, то вариантов кроме `AppCompatActivity` у вас и нет. Если же вы не используете эту тему (например, минимальный API приложения > 20 и используется тема *Material*), причин использовать `AppCompatActivity` тоже нет, так как все ее расширение от наследованных выше активити заключается (в основоном) в поддержке своей темы и весь этот код будет лишним и бесполезным грузом.

Что каcается книги, то изложение там ведется от простого к сложному.  Причины использовать `FragmentActivity` там ясно указаны в главе 7 (преимущество использования `Fragment` из библиотеки поддержки. Данная активити реализует, собственно, поддержку фрагментов из этой библиотеки поддержки , для чего и нужна в фреймворке). При этом при создании приложения используется дефолтная тема текущей версии API.

Упоминание о библиотеке *AppCompat* и, соответственно, использование `AppCompatActivity` начинается только в главе 13 (использование Material-вида диалога чуть раньше в главе 12), там же и явно указано, что теперь нужно использовать `AppCompatActivity`  (есть отдельная глава об этом) и прочие манипуляции, связанные с переходом на библиотеку поддержки *AppCompat*, только в этой главе "мы узнаем" о данной активити.

Answer (score 0):

`AppCompatActivity` наследует `FragmentActivity`, если  внимательнее посмотрите и вам станет ясно то, что `AppCompatActivity` это переработанный `FragmentActivity`, который имеет дополнительные методы.

Comment: основная причина существования AppCompatActivity - имплементация темы AppCompat