# Различия между Activity и AppCompatActivity

Tags: android, android-sdk, activity, android-toolbar

Разбираюсь, почему на обычном Activity метод getActioBar() выплёвывает null. Понял, что в обычном Activity он не предусмотрен, поэтому хочу спросить: кроме него есть ли какие-то весомые различия?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/652151/177345

Comment: Стоит заметить, что метод `getActionBar()` ( https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getActionBar() ) принадлежит классу `Activity` и доступен с API 11, поэтому в "обычной" активити он, естественно, предусмотрен и "выплевывает" NPE по другим причинам. Более того, `AppCompatActivity` наследует метод `getActionBar()` именно от класса `Activity`, а не реализует свой. Ищите причину NPE в своем коде.

Comment: Вообще, в полной мере ознакомиться с назначением класса `AppCompatActivity`, всех реализуемых им методах и их назначением вы можете в [официальной документации](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html).